# HTTP uri in a GTK# FileChooserDialog

Tags: file, dialog, gtk

Can GTK#'s [FileChooserDialog](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aGtk.FileChooserDialog) be used as a unified file/URI dialog? I'd like it to accept http/https/ftp URIs without "rewriting" them (prepending local directory).

Even if I set `LocalOnly=false` and paste a http://.... uri into the text box inside the filechooser, I cannot get the original entry. Local directory is always prepended to the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution / hack after all (in C#):

```
private string _extractUri(Widget wi) {
    if (wi is Entry)
        return ((wi as Entry).Text);
    else if (wi is Container) {
        foreach (Widget w in (wi as Container).Children) {
            string x = _extractUri(w);
            if (x!=null)
                return x;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm not sure if that's always safe, but it worked for the standard FileChooserDialog. It will return the original string from the input field - even if standard Uri / File results are mangled.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research, and I don't think it's possible. At least not with the direct native C GTK+ API, which is what I tested.

In my testing, I always either got the local directory's path prepended to the http:// URI I had entered in the dialog, or I got back (null). I did call the `get_uri()` method, not just `get_filename()`.

I also took a quick look, as a reference, at the [GIMP](http://gimp.org/) application's File menu. As you probably know, GIMP provides the G in GTK+, so it can sometimes be used as a reference for ideas on how to use the toolkit. GIMP does not try to support URIs entered in the file chooser dialog, instead it has a dedicated [Open Location](http://docs.gimp.org/en/ch05s03s02.html) command, that opens a simple dialog with just a GtkEntry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set [local-only](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-local-only) to FALSE and then use the GIO [get_file ()/get_files ()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-get-file) calls which return a GFile* accessible through the `GIO` File API and therefore through `gvfs`.